# Как реализовать соединение данных из input в echo php

Tags: javascript, php

Может я до конца не понимаю как это сделать, прошу подсказку или пример .
И так есть форма в неё вводим значение то есть сумму число ( сумма пополнения) например 10

```
<input type="number" step="any" name="change_amount" min="<?php echo $settings["min_deposit_balance"]; ?>" max="<?php echo $settings["max_deposit_balance"]; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $ULang->t("Минимальная сумма"); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $settings["min_deposit_balance"]; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $settings["currency_main"]["sign"]; ?>" class="form-control pay-summ" >

и есть вывод бонус за пополнение 
<?php echo $Profile->calcBonus(10) ; ?>
```

как в calcBonus(10) перенести данные из input сумма пополнения, чтобы эти данные подставились в

```
<?php echo $Profile->calcBonus(10) ; ?> в calcBonus(значение из input)
```

Comment: Извещение про бонус на новой странице? У тебя в переменной POST длжно приходить значение с твоего инпута change_amount, вот его и вставляй.

Comment: Значение calcBonus(10) ; выводится из бд-- 10 это статическая сумма, нужно чтобы в  calcBonus() подставлялась динамически сумма из поле input,  это действие происходит на текущей странице, смысл таков чтобы при вводе вводе в поле input моментально отображалась скидка, скорее всего это делается через слушатель, но не понятно как это реализовать, тем более с подстановкой значения из input в <?php echo $Profile->calcBonus(значение input) ; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно не силен в ооп, но логически как-то так:

```
        <form method='post'>
        <input type="number" step="any" name="change_amount" ...bla-bla-bla... >
    </form>
<?php echo $Profile->calcBonus($_POST['change_amount']) ; ?>
```